# How can we send metrics from JMeter to Grafana Cloud using Graphite TSDB?

Tags: jmeter, grafana, graphite

I am trying to send metrics from JMeter to Grafana Cloud using Graphite. But i am getting error sending metrics to Graphite in Jmeter logs. I am using Grafana cloud Graphite Url as host in my backend listener.
Can anyone who tried this way of sending metrics help?

I tried backend listener (GraphiteBackendListenerClient) in JMeter and using Grafana cloud Graphite URL as host. I expected to be able to send metrics to Graphite which is added as a data source in Grafana Cloud. But i am getting error sending metrics to Graphite. I am assuming that port 2003 is not open on Graphite server to allow the incoming traffic. Any help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

If you "assume" that the port is not opened you can check it using [telnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/telnet) or equivalent.

Also it worth looking at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, you might also want to [increase JMeter's debug logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the Backend Listener by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend" level="debug" />
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for your answer. 
I tried Telnet and i am getting connection refused error. Grafana cloud team said that they cannot open the port due to security reasons and traffic should be sent to Graphite only using https. Is there anyway we can send traffic to Graphite in Grafana Cloud without using the port? Thank you once again.